# Telegraf.JS i18n - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't') in WizardScene

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Everything works, but in the second stage of the scene, i18n is undefined. i18n is registered, as are the scenes in the bot.

```js
const createPostHere = new Scenes.WizardScene('createPostHere',
    async (ctx) => {
        ctx.wizard.state.post = {}
        await ctx.reply(await ctx.i18n.t('createPost.promptTitle')) << everything works
        ctx.wizard.next()
    },
    async (ctx) => {
        ctx.wizard.state.post.title = ctx.message.text
        await ctx.reply(await ctx.i18n.t('createPost.promptText')) << node crashes
        ctx.wizard.next()
    },
```

Everything registered

```js
bot.use(stage.middleware());
bot.use(i18n.middleware())
```

I really don`t know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
async (ctx) => {
   await ctx.replyWithHTML(
       ctx.i18n.t('create-text')
   )

   ctx.scene.state.i18n = ctx.i18n
   ctx.wizard.next()
},

async (ctx) => {
   const { i18n } = ctx.scene.state
   await ctx.replyWithHTML(i18n.t('create-details'))

   await ctx.scene.leave()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use i18n first before stage middleware. Like this:

```
bot.use(i18n.middleware());
bot.use(stage.middleware());
```